# Method render does not exist

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-pagination

I am trying to render my view but i got error 
its says Method render does not exist . (View:
my view is

```
@foreach($forumindex->forumindex()->paginate(2) as $comment)
<p><div class="well">{{ $comment->comment }}</div></p>
@endforeach

{!! $forumindex->forumindex->render() !!}
```

when i remove `{!! $forumindex->forumindex->render() !!}` its working fine and i see only 2 post
help me i don't know what code is right

Answer (score 0):

The render() method to build the paginator view has been renamed to links() on Laravel 5.2.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination